# scrapy pass item to multiple method

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried to pass my item to 2 different method as below. the reason why I pass it through 2 methods is because in each page, I try to get some data in each page, and then in each of those pages, get the relevant links and go through them to collect more data.
the problem seems to come from the fact that I pass `item` through 2 loops. It increase the number of item from **23** after the first loop (what it is supposed to be) to **248** item after `yield scrapy.Request(url=final_url, callback=self.parse_sports, meta={'event_item': item, 'discipline': event_name})`
I still need to go through `final_url`. But how I can stop it from creating the unnecessary items since as of now, it creates a new item each time the for loop was run

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from eventSpider.items import EventspiderItem
import urllib.parse

class EventsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'eventSpider'
    
    # base url to link to the end url we receive
    baseUrl = "http://www.olympedia.org"
    
    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [
            'http://www.olympedia.org/editions'
        ]
        
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_urls)
            
    def parse_urls(self, response):
        """
        Go through the table of owinter olympics
        Get all the url to those olympics events
        Send the urls down to parse items to get the items of interest
        """        
        # remove the last 2 as the events haven't happened yet
        for tr in response.xpath("//table[2]//tr")[:-2]:
            url = tr.xpath('td[1]//a//@href').extract_first()
            # check for None. In this case, we elimiate the 2 events that was canelled
            if url is None:
                continue
            else:
                url_to_check = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseUrl, url)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url_to_check, callback=self.parse_items)

    def parse_items(self, response):
    """
    Get the items of interest
    Extract the list of disciplines and their url
    pass the url 
    """
    item = EventspiderItem()
    selector = Selector(response)
    table1_rows = selector.xpath("//table[1]//tr")
    
    item['event_title'] = table1_rows[1].xpath('td//text()').extract_first()
    item['event_place'] = table1_rows[2].xpath('td//text()').extract_first()

    table2 = selector.xpath("//table[3]//tr")
    
    discipline_list = []
    url_list = []

    for tr in table2:            
        urls = tr.xpath('td//a//@href').extract()
        disciplines = tr.xpath('td//a//text()').extract()
        
        for url in urls:
            # # check if we get empty list
            # if not url:
            #     continue
            # else:
            url_list.append(url)   
        for discipline in disciplines:
            discipline_list.append(discipline)
    for i, url in enumerate(url_list):
        final_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseUrl, url)
        event_name = item['event_title'] + " " + discipline_list[i]
        yield scrapy.Request(url=final_url, callback=self.parse_sports, meta={'event_item': item, 'discipline': event_name})

    def parse_sports(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        item = response.meta.get('event_item')
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the list and only when you're done with it yield the item.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
# from eventSpider.items import EventspiderItem
import urllib.parse


class EventspiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    event_title = scrapy.Field()
    event_place = scrapy.Field()


class EventsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'eventSpider'

    # base url to link to the end url we receive
    baseUrl = "http://www.olympedia.org"

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = [
            'http://www.olympedia.org/editions'
        ]

        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_urls)

    def parse_urls(self, response):
        """
        Go through the table of owinter olympics
        Get all the url to those olympics events
        Send the urls down to parse items to get the items of interest
        """
        # remove the last 2 as the events haven't happened yet
        for tr in response.xpath("//table[2]//tr")[:-2]:
            url = tr.xpath('td[1]//a//@href').extract_first()
            # check for None. In this case, we elimiate the 2 events that was canelled
            if url is None:
                continue
            else:
                url_to_check = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseUrl, url)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url_to_check, callback=self.parse_items)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        """
        Get the items of interest
        Extract the list of disciplines and their url
        pass the url
        """
        item = EventspiderItem()
        selector = Selector(response)
        table1_rows = selector.xpath("//table[1]//tr")

        item['event_title'] = table1_rows[1].xpath('td//text()').extract_first()
        item['event_place'] = table1_rows[2].xpath('td//text()').extract_first()

        table2 = selector.xpath("//table[3]//tr")

        discipline_list = []
        url_list = []

        for tr in table2:
            urls = tr.xpath('td//a//@href').extract()
            disciplines = tr.xpath('td//a//text()').extract()

            for url in urls:
                url_list.append(url)
            for discipline in disciplines:
                discipline_list.append(discipline)

        if url_list:
            final_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseUrl, url_list[0])
            yield scrapy.Request(url=final_url, callback=self.parse_sports, meta={'event_item': item, 'url_list': url_list[1:], 'discipline_list': discipline_list})

    def parse_sports(self, response):
        event_item = response.meta['event_item']
        url_list = response.meta['url_list']
        discipline_list = response.meta['discipline_list']

        # extract what you want before, example:
        # title = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
        # and add it to the item if that's what you want...
        # item['title'] = title

        if url_list:
            final_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self.baseUrl, url_list[0])
            event_name = event_item['event_title'] + " " + discipline_list[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(url=final_url, callback=self.parse_sports, meta={'event_item': event_item, 'url_list': url_list[1:], 'discipline_list': discipline_list})
        else:
            yield event_item
```

```py
 'item_scraped_count': 23,
```

Comment: Thank you! this solve the problem of repeated item. However it seems to introduce a new problem: every item I scrape from that point onward only save the information of the last scraped item. in other word, I have 23 items, but all those items are duplicated

Comment: I'm getting 23 unique items, did you copy the copy as is?

Comment: yes but I have actually found the problem now. it is due to way I parse the items. your solution is perfectly correct. thank you once again

Comment: @leMinhNguyen No problem!